# Tests: How to check if a sidekiq job enqueued another sidekiq job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

I have this two example class, and I want to write a rspec that runs PaymentCheckJob for first time, and if payment_type == 'ticket', I want to check if it enqueued another sidekiq job

```
class ApplicationJob
  include Sidekiq::Job
  sidekiq_options retry: 1

  def perform(*args)
    # Do something
  end
end

class PaymentCheckJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(args = '{}')
    args = JSON.parse(args)
    invoice_id = args['invoice_id']
    if invoice.payment_type == 'ticket'
      ::PaymentCheckJob.perform_at(1.hour.from_now, { 'invoice_id': invoice.id }.to_json)
      # ::PaymentCheckJob.perform_in(3600, { 'invoice_id': invoice.id }.to_json)
    else
      invoice.payed_at = Time.now
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stub this method, write two different contexts: when job is enqueued and when not

Something like this

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe PaymentCheckJob, type: :job do
  describe '#perform' do
    subject(:perform_job) { described_class.new.perform(invoice_id: invoice.id) }

    let(:invoice) { Invoice.create(payment_type: payment_type) }

    before { allow(described_class).to receive(:perform_at) }

    context 'when invoice is ticket' do
      let(:payment_type) { 'ticket' }

      it 'enqueues another PaymentCheckJob' do
        perform_job

        expect(described_class).to have_received(:perform_at)
      end
    end

    context 'when invoice is not ticket' do
      let(:payment_type) { 'not_ticket' }

      it 'does not enqueue another PaymentCheckJob' do
        perform_job

        expect(described_class).not_to have_received(:perform_at)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can also check jobs size like

```rb
expect { perform_job }.to change { PaymentCheckJob.jobs.size }.by(1)
expect { perform_job }.not_to change { PaymentCheckJob.jobs.size }
```

You can also read hints about testing of Sidekiq in the [docs](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Testing)

---

But I don't sure it's good idea to invoke one job from another. Probably you can schedule this job with cron (for example 1 per 5 minutes) and instead of passing some arguments fetch batch of these invoices (for example some scope like `Invoice.not_processed`) inside the job body. To exclude race condition you can [lock](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) these invoices for update. Also to ensure no two jobs run at the same time lock body of perform method [with advisory locking](https://github.com/ClosureTree/with_advisory_lock) (mutex). And of course update invoices if needed. In this case, you will be more in managing the processes, and jobs will not somehow messy invoke each other. I think so